# Looking for a unsigned 128bit Integer Datatype for the .net Framework

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Int128 in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227731/int128-in-net)

as I'm working on a tool which manages IP devices and I'd like to add IPv6 Support to it, I'm searching for a 128bit unsigned Integer .net Datatype to do basic IP related calculations (Subnetting, List all Hosts for a Subnet, ..)

It should support the standard arithmetic/logic methods.

Thank you :)

Comment: @Scott Weinstein: If you are after performance, I would say no. BigInteger is rather slow.

Comment: Isn't only one 64bit part of a ipv6 address interesting. the host part is (most of the time) generated from the mac address?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967464/datatype-for-storing-a-long-serial-number-10-bytes

Answer (score 4):

in this article the author describes and shows how to implement the Int128 datatype in .NET: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=636

also please search here in SO before posting :)

[Int128 in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227731/int128-in-net)

Comment: I know there are several ways to represent Integers >64 bit on .net (System.Numerics.BigInteger for example) but they are all signed. I'm searching for an unsigned type.