# Convert GUID to Numeric Equivalent

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, type-conversion, guid

I've been asked to export a list of users from ActiveDirectory, and Convert the GUIDs to a numeric equivalent for display (so I'll .ToString that after). I've done some searching but most of the questions are on converting something TO a GUID, or converting a GUID to Int or something silly, (I understand Ints are too small etc..), which arn't really appropriate.

I have the AD stuff sorted and the data exported, however I'm wondering what data type / format to use to convert the GUIDs to, and if it is even possible. I'm not really bothered what exact numeric type is used, as long as the number is still "unique" (I understand that GUIDs arn't really unique etc..).

Are GUIDs in hex based format, and is there any suitable numeric type I can convert them to for display?

I'm using VB.Net and .Net Framework 4. I've tried using BigInteger, but that seems to go into negative numbers too, which I'll use if I have to, but would rather not if there's something else more suitable.

**Edit**
Here's what I tried:

Using a GUID of: f02c7caf-7e5a-491b-9f23-9476174bdda1

And this code:

```
Dim Foo As String = (New System.Numerics.BigInteger(adUserDirectoryRecord.Guid.ToByteArray())).ToString
```

It came out as: 
-125127638954164478915246035839554388817

**Note:** I'll be outputting this in .csv format once I'm done, for another team to pick up and import into another system, this is likely why they want it in numeric rather than alphanumeric format.

**SOLUTION:**

As there will be no need to ever convert the Numeric GUID back, BigInteger was the correct method to use for this. The change was to Resize the ByteArray to force it to Positive values only:

```
'Gets the User's GUID from the Active Directory record, converts it to a Byte Array and Resizes it to Force Positive Values Only:
Dim bytGUIDBytes As Byte() = adUserDirectoryRecord.Guid.ToByteArray()
Array.Resize(bytGUIDBytes, 17)

'Converts the User's GUID Bytes into a Numeric Equivalent, and Returns the String version of the Numerical value.
Return New System.Numerics.BigInteger(bytGUIDBytes).ToString
```

Comment: If you believe a GUID isn't really unique, why would converting to a numeric representation change that?

Comment: You need a 128-bit unsigned integer data type. Please see this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283200/looking-for-a-unsigned-128bit-integer-datatype-for-the-net-framework

Comment: I'm not wanting to change the "uniqueness", the reason I've been asked to convert them to a numeric equivalent is that it will be a more suitable format for display / input into another system. I only mentioned the part about them being "Unique" to show that wasn't a requirement as I understand they're not, (due to them just being a large 128 bit value with a small chance for collision).

Comment: `BigInteger` looks like the only real choice you have. Not sure where you get the idea of it being able to be negative comes to play - it completely depends on how you represent the GUID.

Comment: Edited the code I tried using for BigInteger, and how it came out as. Let me know if I'm being a complete nab heh. I'll have a look at the 128-bit unsigned one now too. Only some of the values were negative btw, this one: "1c30c658-7da4-4d04-be57-cc8412c91868"
  came out as: "138368404917772402407527972134244632152"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Numeric" doesn't make sense in VB w.r.t `Guid`.  There is no 128-bit numeric types in .net.  The only 128-bit type is Decimal; but that doesn't seem to make sense to convert a `Guid` to a `Decimal`.  I would simply use `ToByteArray` and display the byte values as hex.

Alternatively, make sure the last byte in the array given to BigInteger is zero to get a postive value.  e.g.::

```
var bytes = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(); 
Array.Resize(ref bytes, 17); 
var bigInt = new BigInteger(bytes);
var value = bigInt.ToString();
```

Comment: Hmm I sort of did that with the BigInteger conversion (Edited my post up top to show what I used). I believe they're asking me to convert it to numeric as they'll be importing it into another system, which doesn't allow alpha-numerics for that field, so barebone Hex probably wouldn't be suitable. Is this request complete lunacy then? Based on the structure of GUIDs.

Comment: I don't believe they're wanting to convert it back, only store it as a numerical value (rather than a GUID), in whatever field they're importing it to. I'll check with them that it will support a number that long though! Otherwise they'll probably have to use a different field. What I was checking was that you CAN convert a GUID to a numerical equivalent (without losing data), and what type would be most suitable. I've used BigInt, but as I've edited in my initial post, for some of the IDs it converts them to negative values. :S

Comment: Thanks, I've checked with the team and the field they're importing it to will take the size. I've just tried your method like this: `Dim GUIDBytes As Byte() = adUserDirectoryRecord.Guid.ToByteArray()
Array.Resize(bytGUIDBytes, 17)
Dim Blah As String = New System.Numerics.BigInteger(bytGUIDBytes).ToString` and got: "215154727966773984548128571592213822639"   When it was: "-125127638954164478915246035839554388817"   before. Is this still correct?

Comment: It does give all positive values at least, which is great. Since it won't be converted back either ways as long as the "Uniqueness" is still preserved, its all good btw.

Comment: Thankyou! I've edited the solution into my initial post. Job done. Cheers for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply convert Guid to numeric representation using ToString("n") :

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n")
```

will return something like "5ee575bd995b419499aff6d6967c4a35"

Comment: That's alphanumeric.

Comment: No, that's hexadecimal which is numeric

Comment: Ah-ha of course. Interesting. Would have been slightly less code too.

Comment: If you want the result as decimal: `Convert.ToInt64(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"), 16);`

Comment: Won't that throw an exception? I mean Guid is 128 and you're converting to int64.