# Converting guids to numeric value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, primary-key, guid

What is the best way to obtain the numeric value from a guid column?

I am trying this line but i am getting:

```
ORA-00904: "HASHBYTES": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Query is below:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5',CAST(prod AS varchar2(30)))
FROM PRODS;
```

Please advice.

Comment: What numeric value?  Are you trying to convert those 36 characters into 18hexadecimal values and then into a decimal?  I'm curious, once it is a decimal number, what are you going to do with that value?

Comment: Your prose says numeric value but your code says varchar2.  That's inconsistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle doesn't have the `HASHBYTES` function. You can convert hex to decimal using `TO_NUMBER(hex-string, 'xx')`, but you must have enough `x` characters in your format string to cover the input value. In the case of a GUID, that's 32 `x` characters:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(prod, RPAD('x', 32, 'x'))
FROM PRODS;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly.  I hope you have a fine day

Answer (score 1):

This will convert MD5 hash (hex) to decimal number

```
SELECT CONV('MD5', 16, 10)
FROM PRODS;
```

Comment: Do you want to convert GUID to string, or hash to string??? My answer is to your title of question.

Comment: My purpose in life was to obtain 02122304813AEF67342CB1 To a numeric value.. like 91, if it's possible.

Comment: Then its simple - SELECT CONV('MD5', 16, 10)

Comment: but for your information, CONV works with 64-bit precision - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv

Comment: CONV is used in MySQL, CONVERT is used in MSSQL

Answer (score 1):

GUIDs don't really lend themselves to being represented as numerics.
However, you can do it if you need to.

This question has been asked before in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849509/convert-guid-to-numeric-equivalent) post