# What is the .NET System.Numerics.BigInteger Equivalent of Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger.ToByteArrayUnsigned?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, bouncycastle, biginteger, system.numerics

I am currently working with the [.NET port of BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) and I am having some trouble converting a big integer into a `System.Guid` using the native .NET `BigInteger`.

For some context, I am using BouncyCastle in one ("source") application to convert a `System.Guid` to a `Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger`.  This value is then saved as a string in the format `3A2B847A960F0E4A8D49BD62DDB6EB38`.

Then, in another ("destination") application, I am taking this saved string value of a `BigInteger` and am trying to convert it back into a `System.Guid`.

Please note that in the destination application I do not want BouncyCastle as a reference and would like to use core .NET libraries for the conversion.  However, since I am running into problems converting with core .NET classes, I am using BouncyCastle and the following code does exactly what I would like:

```
var data = "3A2B847A960F0E4A8D49BD62DDB6EB38";
var integer = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger( data, 16 );
var bytes = integer.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
var guid = new Guid( bytes ); // holds expected value: (7A842B3A-0F96-4A0E-8D49-BD62DDB6EB38)
```

As you can see, there is a `ToByteArrayUnsigned` method on the `Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger` that makes this work.  If I use the `ToByteArray` on the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` (even when [resizing the array as discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849509/convert-guid-to-numeric-equivalent)) it does not work and I get a different `System.Guid` than expected.

So, what is the best way to perform the equivalent to the above operation using native .NET classes?

### Solution

Thanks to @John-Tasler's suggestion, it turns out this was due to endianess... darn you endianess... will your endiness ever end? :P

`var parsed = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse( "3A2B847A960F0E4A8D49BD62DDB6EB38", NumberStyles.HexNumber ).ToByteArray();
    Array.Resize( ref parsed, 16 );
    var guid = new Guid( parsed.Reverse().ToArray() ); // Hoorrrrayyyy!`

Comment: "// expected value" -- I think you forgot to actually put the expected value in your question there, right?

Comment: Good point.  I updated the code to say that the "guid" variable has the expected value, but never put what that was anywhere.  I have updated the code comment to reflect this.  Thank you @hvd!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the actual value of the resulting Guid when using .NET's BigIntegrer?

It could be that the two implementations are just storing the bytes differently. Endianess, etc.

To see what comes back from each implementation's array of bytes:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var b in bytes)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2} ", b);
} 
sb.ToString();
```

It'd be an interesting comparison.

Comment: Of course, a more terse way to print that out:

    string.Join(" ", bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid `BigInteger` here entirely. Your `data` bytes are already in the correct order so you can convert to `byte[]` directly.

```
var data = "3A2B847A960F0E4A8D49BD62DDB6EB38";
var bytes = new byte[16];
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  bytes[i] = byte.Parse(data.Substring(i * 2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var guid = new Guid(bytes); // 7a842b3a-0f96-4a0e-8d49-bd62ddb6eb38
```