# Signing ECDSA with private key with curve secp224k1

Tags: authentication, cryptography, bouncycastle, signature, ecdsa

I want to get sign by ECDSA secp224k1. I cannot get the same signature as in the [CoinFLEX Authentication Process](https://github.com/coinflex-exchange/API/blob/master/AUTH.md) example from the manual. I am using C# BouncyCastle.

Why can't I get manual page's signature ​​by my code?

```
// manual page's step 7
byte[] fortyByteMessage  = fromHexStringToByteArr("0x00000000 00000001").Concat(fromHexStringToByteArr("0x6b347302 2e6b9b5a f2fe5d1d ae7cf5bf")).Concat(fromHexStringToByteArr("0xf08c98ca f1fd82e8 cea9825d bff04fd0")).ToArray();

// manual page's step 9
byte[] privateKey = fromHexStringToByteArr("0xb89ea7fc d22cc059 c2673dc2 4ff40b97 83074646 86560d0a d7561b83");

// manual page's step 10
X9ECParameters spec = ECNamedCurveTable.GetByName("secp224k1");
ECDomainParameters domain = new ECDomainParameters(spec.Curve, spec.G, spec.N);
ECDsaSigner signer = new ECDsaSigner(new HMacDsaKCalculator(new Sha224Digest()));
signer.Init(true, new ECPrivateKeyParameters(new BigInteger(privateKey), domain));
BigInteger[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature(fortyByteMessage);
byte[] r = signature[0].ToByteArray().SkipWhile(b => b == 0x00).Reverse().ToArray(); // (r) r should be 0x3fb77a9d 7b5b2a68 209e76f6 872078c5 791340d5 989854ad a3ab735e, but not.

Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(r).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower());
```

Expected byteArr ( step 10 r value ):

```
r = 0x3fb77a9d 7b5b2a68 209e76f6 872078c5 791340d5 989854ad a3ab735e<br>
```

My byteArr (this is wrong value, because it is different from step 10 r value )

```
r = 0x1e3b3f4f 7401ff9d 827b7222 47823919 452d3adb effa7aa4 52a0879e<br>
```

Another function:

```
static byte[] fromHexStringToByteArr(string paramHexString)
{
    string hexString = paramHexString.Substring(2).Replace(" ", "");
    byte[] result = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];

    int cur = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i = i + 2)
    {
        string w = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
        result[cur] = Convert.ToByte(w, 16);
        cur++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- According to step 10 of the [instructions](https://github.com/coinflex-exchange/API/blob/master/AUTH.md), not the 40-byte-message should be signed, but the SHA224-hash of this message: *The client signs the 28-byte SHA-224 digest of the 40-byte message...*. Note, that the data are not automatically hashed by the [`GenerateSignature`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html)-method, i.e. it must be hashed *explicitly*, see also [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/signers/ECDSASigner.java) and these [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.ECDSASigner&method=generateSignature).
- The [`Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger.ToByteArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542277/what-is-the-net-system-numerics-biginteger-equivalent-of-org-bouncycastle-math)-method (which is used in the C#-code) outputs the byte-array in big-endian-format (unlike .Net, whose [`System.Numerics.BigInteger.ToByteArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.tobytearray?view=netframework-4.8)-method uses the little-endian-format). Therefore, it is not necessary to reverse the byte-order (using the `Reverse`-method).
- With these modifications, the signature is:

  ```
    r = 0x1781ff4997b48d389f518df75001c4b6564082956228d74dd0321656
    s = 0x0aadc68cf78dc75d44fb300f200465e72a70826ec2d5577d49b62e59
  ```

  which, however, still differs from the signature shown in the instructions.

  In the C#-code, the [`ECDsaSigner`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html)-instance is created with a [`HMacDsaKCalculator`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html)-instance, generating a *deterministic* signature based on [RFC6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979). When creating a signature with [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm), the `k`-parameter is chosen randomly for the non-deterministic ECDSA, whereas in the deterministic variant it is created from the message and the private key according to a specific algorithm (described in RFC6979), see [here](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/digital-signatures/ecdsa-sign-verify-messages#ecdsa-sign). Thus, the deterministic variant generates the same signature for the same message and private key, while the non-deterministic variant generates different signatures.

  Probably the difference between the signatures is caused by the use of the non-deterministic variant by CoinFLEX. Unfortunately, the instructions do not go into detail about the ECDSA-procedure used.

**Update:**

*Both* variants, deterministic and non-deterministic, provide *valid* ECDSA-signatures! Before the deterministic variant ([RFC6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979) is from August 2013) there was only the non-deterministic variant, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50752/downsides-of-not-using-deterministic-ecdsa-signatures-for-blockchain-validation/50793#50793).

I installed and tested the [`sign_secp224k1`](https://github.com/coinflex-exchange/libecp#sign_secp224k1)-tool on a Linux (Debian) machine. As suspected, the tool generates *different* signatures for the *same* private key and the *same* message, obviously using the non-deterministic variant. This can also be easily verified from the source-code: The signature is calculated using the [`ecp_sign`](https://github.com/coinflex-exchange/libecp/blob/master/ecp.c)-method, which *randomly* determines the `k`-value using [`/dev/urandom`](https://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom).

Thus it is clear that the signature generated by the C#-code using the deterministic variant *generally cannot match* a signature generated by the `sign_secp224k1`-tool using the non-deterministic variant.

Comment: This is a signature for authentication. So I do n’t think it ’s random.
The following URL is the specification, but it is difficult for me to read.　　　https://github.com/coinflex-exchange/libecp#sign_secp224k1

Comment: The non-deterministic variant generates *valid* ECDSA-signatures just like the deterministic variant! I also  tested the `sign_secp224k1`-tool and indeed it uses the *non-deterministic* variant, see the update-section in my answer.

Comment: When I run the same code as provided above I get exception System.ArgumentException: 'Scalar is not in the interval [1, n - 1]
Parameter name: d' mecause my value of `new BigInteger(privateKey)` is -7517217624485429887806670580524002717199604937162964340004446921853
how did you manage to run it?

Comment: `new BigInteger(1, privateKey)` fixed crashing for me but the api still returns "You sent an incorrect signature." error.  kyounoii, did you manage to get it running?

Comment: @LukAss741 - You should post a new question on SO with an exact description of your problem and all information needed to solve it. There you can refer to this question / answer if needed.